# Android FB SDK3.0 - How to check whether a user is logged in?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Hi I'm using Facebook sdk3.0 for Android. How can I check whether a user is logged in or not?

Currently I'm using this:

```
public static boolean isUserLoggedInWithFacebook() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session != null && session.isOpened()) 
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

But it sometimes gives `false` while user is still logged in.

Comment: seems to be fine the method.. did you find any better version ?

Comment: Back then it wasn't working well so I had to mix with the old APIs. I'm not sure about now though.

Answer (score 0):

try using `facebook.isSessionValid()`. It should return false if the user is logged out.

Comment: This works perfectly. Just that I'm trying to avoid old APIs. I know facebook.isSessionValid() is not. But I didn't use facebook.authorize() to log user in at the beginning. All I deal with is session. If I create a Facebook object in my function using Facebook fb = new Facebook("my_api_key"); I have to set its access token and expire date and those functions are expired.:S

Comment: Can you give more details on how you're creating and closing the sessions, and what you mean by "the user is still logged in" when the session is not open?

Also, just because a session is still open on the client side, doesn't always mean the user is still "logged in", or that your app is still authorized. The only way to determine that is to make a "me" request, and make sure there aren't any errors.